# Query a subdocument and select filtered data from it Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to query a subdocument that lives within a parent document and only select (return in the express response) a specific subdocument with it's own data, but the way I'm doing it, it's selecting/returning all the subdocuments, without filtering the one I need, which I'm trying to filter by the field `candidateId`

Here is my query:

```
interviewRouter.get(
  "/:idCandidato&:userEmail",
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { idCandidato, userEmail } = req.params;

    parseInt(idCandidato);

    const infoCandidato = await User.find({
      email: userEmail,
      "candidates.candidateId": idCandidato,
    }).select({"_id": 0, "candidates": 1});

    infoCandidato
      ? res.status(200).json({ Candidato: infoCandidato })
      : res.status(404).json({ Candidato: "Candidato no encontrado" });
  }
);
```

Here is my document and subdocument structure:

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61223b3c88e21fe0ee69d689"),
    "username" : "randomUserName",
    "email" : "random@email.com",
    "pictureUrl" : "some/url/to/the/user/picture/username",
    "role" : "admin",
    "candidates" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("612242cd11a7f1ebc6a18661"),
            "candidateName" : "some candidates name",
            "candidateId" : 123,
            "candidateInfo" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("612242cd11a7f1ebc6a18662"),
                    "currentSituation" : "3",
                    "motivationToChange" : "3",
                    "postSavingDate" : ISODate("2021-08-22T12:27:57.490Z")
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("612242cd11a7f1ebc6a04854"),
                    "currentSituation" : "6",
                    "motivationToChange" : "7",
                    "postSavingDate" : ISODate("2021-08-22T13:56:57.490Z")
                }
            ],
            "availableNow" : false,
            "mainSkills" : "MM"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("612261abf7b68bfaf56345df"),
            "candidateName" : "some other guy",
            "candidateId" : 1234,
            "candidateInfo" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("612261abf7b68bfaf56345e0"),
                    "currentSituation" : "dunno",
                    "motivationToChange" : "no idea",
                    "postSavingDate" : ISODate("2021-08-22T14:39:39.161Z")
                }
            ],
            "availableNow" : false,
            "mainSkills" : "JavaScript"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Below, you can see what my query returns, *which basically is the whole `candidates` collection, instead of the filtered subdocuments that I need*:

```json
{
    "Candidato": [
        {
            "candidates": [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("612242cd11a7f1ebc6a18661"),
            "candidateName" : "some candidates name",
            "candidateId" : 123,
            "candidateInfo" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("612242cd11a7f1ebc6a18662"),
                    "currentSituation" : "3",
                    "motivationToChange" : "3",
                    "postSavingDate" : ISODate("2021-08-22T12:27:57.490Z")
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("612242cd11a7f1ebc6a04854"),
                    "currentSituation" : "6",
                    "motivationToChange" : "7",
                    "postSavingDate" : ISODate("2021-08-22T13:56:57.490Z")
                }
            ],
            "availableNow" : false,
            "mainSkills" : "MM"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("612261abf7b68bfaf56345df"),
            "candidateName" : "some other guy",
            "candidateId" : 1234,
            "candidateInfo" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("612261abf7b68bfaf56345e0"),
                    "currentSituation" : "dunno",
                    "motivationToChange" : "no idea",
                    "postSavingDate" : ISODate("2021-08-22T14:39:39.161Z")
                }
            ],
            "availableNow" : false,
            "mainSkills" : "JavaScript"
        }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

##### Important Note: remember that I just want it to return either `123` or `1234` subdocument, depending on the `candidateId` I pass down to the query

Here is a workaround I found but I think is a bit dirty and would appreciate another alternative:

```js
interviewRouter.get(
  "/:idCandidato&:userEmail",
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { idCandidato, userEmail } = req.params;

    const infoCandidato = await User.findOne(
      {
        email: userEmail,
        "candidates.candidateId": idCandidato,
      },
      function (err: any, response: any) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(400).send(err);
        } else {
          let newResponse = response["candidates"].filter((element: any) => {
            return element.candidateId === parseInt(idCandidato);
          });
          res.status(200).json({ Candidato: newResponse });
        }
      }
    );
```

With this workaround, I get what I need, but it looks a bit messy and I feel there might be some other cleaner solution. This is what I get returned:

```json
{
    "Candidato": [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("612242cd11a7f1ebc6a18661"),
            "candidateName" : "some candidates name",
            "candidateId" : 123,
            "candidateInfo" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("612242cd11a7f1ebc6a18662"),
                    "currentSituation" : "3",
                    "motivationToChange" : "3",
                    "postSavingDate" : ISODate("2021-08-22T12:27:57.490Z")
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("612242cd11a7f1ebc6a04854"),
                    "currentSituation" : "6",
                    "motivationToChange" : "7",
                    "postSavingDate" : ISODate("2021-08-22T13:56:57.490Z")
                }
            ],
            "availableNow" : false,
            "mainSkills" : "MM"
        },
    ]
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

##### Issue solved by @eol - Simple note

As said, @eol worked it out and shared the solution. I took his answer and translated it into JavaScript/Mongoose sintaxis and here it goes:

```
interviewRouter.get(
  "/:idCandidato&:userEmail",
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { idCandidato, userEmail } = req.params;
    const infoCandidato = await User.aggregate([
      {
        "$match": {
          email: userEmail
        }
      },
      {
        "$unwind": "$candidates"
      },
      {
        "$match": {
          "candidates.candidateId": parseInt(idCandidato)
        }
      }]);
      infoCandidato.length !== 0
      infoCandidato
      ? res.status(200).json({ Candidato: infoCandidato })
      : res.status(404).json({ Candidato: "Candidato no encontrado" });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple aggregation where you first [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) documents with the given `email`, then [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the candidates elements and the filter those who [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) the given `id`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      email: "random@email.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$candidates"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "candidates.candidateId": 1234
    }
  }
])
```

Here's an example on mongoplayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/GPB3oYqe5em